# How to get Prisma client to generate relationship types

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, postgresql, prisma

I am trying to create a one-to-many relationship between a user and posts. I can create the database schema and can write / query all ok but it appears the prisma client that is being generated doesn't have the relationships on the type.

For example, my schema looks like this:

```
model User {
  id    Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  posts Post[]
}

model Post {
  id       Int  @id @default(autoincrement())
  author   User @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId Int
}
```

I then run `npx prisma generate` which creates a client with the following types

```js
/**
 * Model User
 * 
 */
export type User = {
  id: number
}

/**
 * Model Post
 * 
 */
export type Post = {
  id: number
  authorId: number
}
```

I would expect the user type to look like this:

```js
export type User = {
  id: number;
  posts: Post[];
}
```

Have I defined my Prisma schema correctly? What do I need to do to get the type to include the relation?

Comment: I've noticed that the `ctx.prisma.menu.findFirst` method has a return type of ```(User & {
  posts: Post[];
})``` Is the only way to combine the types manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, a Prisma type will not include relational fields in the base "type". If you want to get the type of your `User` which includes related `Posts`, the Prisma client will include that based on the structure of your query.

https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/select-fields

You can use the `include` attribute on any Prisma CRUD operation to have the Prisma client return specific relational fields, AND those related fields are included in the emitted type. Prisma will take care of this typing for you!

```
const usersWithPosts = await prisma.user.findMany({
  include: {
    posts: true
  }
});

// usersWithPosts has a type like this:
// Array<User & { posts: Array<Post> }>
```

========

EDIT: If you want to compute the type in advance without wanting to write a query, you can use `Prisma.UserGetPayload` (or some other form of `GetPayload`, as the prefix will change based on the model.)

```js
type UserWithPosts = Prisma.UserGetPayload<{
  include: {
    posts: true;
  };
}>;
```

This emits the following type:

```
type UserWithPosts = User & {
    posts: Post[];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shea. I understand the prisma client handles the return types and how to use includes. I was wondering if Prisma generated these types that include the related field for us because it is a bit cumbersome having to manually extend the type of `User` each time

Comment: @Stretch0 Looks like you can leverage `Prisma.UserGetPayload` (`User` will change based on your model.) I've updated my original answer!